# Access ForeignKey type from get_context_data using pk_url_kwargs

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a CreateView in which i want to access the type(choice field) of foreign key in my model which is being used in my current model.

```
Class Mymodel1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    type = models.CharField(choices=SomeTypes.choices())

    

Class MyModel2(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField()
    cas = models.ForeignKey(Mymodel1)


Class Mymodel2CreateView(models.Model):
    pk_url_kwargs = 'cas_id'

    def get_context_data(self):
        type = *queryset to access type from model1*
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the field of `ForeignKey` before the object has been created. It does not seem possible, right? The thing you can do is to use [SIGNALS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/) with `post_save` and `created`.

Comment: no bro the model1 objects gets created while creating model2 object we are accessing foreign key

Comment: Mybad i edited the code

Comment: Show how. You need to supply such information, we are not supposed to guess.

Comment: I meant that before creating the model2 object the model1 object already exists in db i need to access that model1 object while creating model2 object

Comment: And yes, in `get_context_data` you are trying to get an Model2 object that is not existing yet and IT IS executed before that creation. You cannot do that there.

Comment: What if i have pk_url_kwargs of cas